# In Java, when a key is pressed such as a letter, how do I prevent the key from outputting the letter that it is assigned to a jTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

In Java, when a key is pressed such as a letter, how do I prevent the key from outputting the letter that it is assigned to a jTextPane? (Similar to how do game developers suppress the normal functions of the keyboard when a part of their application is in focus).

When KeyEvent.consume() doesn't do the job alone, is there another way?

I'm a fairly novice programmer compared to other people on this board, so please be patient with me. Any examples would be appreciated. I'm eager to learn. Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at this page http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5046125

Answer (score 5):

Assign custom DocumentFilter to the document from the JTextPane. You can intercept the insertString() and skip unnecessary input. It's better than key listener if you should also skip the same chars from pasted content.

Comment: This might be a little over my head, but I will try my best.

Comment: The problem is I don't know exactly how I would intercept the insertString() and skip the unnecessary input -- I might need an example. I'm a bit stuck with this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just a sample, I hope this will prevent A to Z getting entered , but does not cover all scenarios such as Shift,Ctrl and Alt presses.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());

public class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter
{
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
    int i = key.getKeyCode();
    if (i >= 65 && i <= 90)
    {
       ((JTextPane)event.getSource()).cancelKey();
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Do I need to extend KeyAdapter in my class to use .consume()? For some reason my evt.consume(); doesn't seem to actually consume the key letter that is inserted.

Comment: Consume will not allow the keys A-Z to be inserted.

Comment: After a quick boolean test, evt.isConsumed() turns out to be true with my code; however, the letter 'e' is oddly still printed to the jTextPane.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: See if this helps http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.help/msg/73cd565f0184896b